# Incremental count each GROUP in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider below table :

```
IP Address
192.168.1.9
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.9
```

I want to write a sql query such that I get following data :

```
IP Address          Count
192.168.1.3           1
192.168.1.4           2
192.168.1.4           2
192.168.1.9           3
192.168.1.9           3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dense_rank()`:

```
select ip_address, dense_rank() over (order by ip_address) as cnt
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks bro! Dense_Rank() indeed!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ip_address, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ip_address) AS count
FROM table1;
```

is what id do